# Asynchronous programming in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, asynchronous

I'm doing the process of adding sequential images directories in a folder in a folder to the Dictionary list value as Texture2d.

At this time, I need to show the loading window with the animator and lose the data after the data is loaded. But animator because the code runs fast, no action has taken place.

Can you help me with this?

The following is the code block.

```
public void DataActives(string defStrings)
{
    atorLoadingPanel.SetBool("ActiveLoad", true);
    TaskAsyncCountDown(2,"Wait");
    this.gameObject.GetComponent<PCManager>().TypeString = defStrings;
    float CaseControl = TimePanelVariablesChanges();
    switch (CaseControl)
    {
        case 0:
            this.gameObject.GetComponent<PCManager>().Daily();
            //Debug.Log("Case 1");
            break;
        case 1:
            this.gameObject.GetComponent<PCManager>().Weekly();
            //Debug.Log("Case 2");
            break;
        case 2:
            this.gameObject.GetComponent<PCManager>().Monthly();
            //Debug.Log("Case 3");
            break;
        case 3:
            this.gameObject.GetComponent<PCManager>().Yearly();
            //Debug.Log("Case 4");
            break;
        default:
            //Debug.Log("Hata Fırlat");
            break;
    }
    this.gameObject.GetComponent<PCManager>().ShowData();
}


public async Task TaskAsyncCountDown(int count, string flag = "")
{
    for (int i = count; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        LogToTUnityConsole(i, flag);
        await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    atorLoadingPanel.SetBool("ActiveLoad", false);
}
```

Comment: Could you please try to point out your problem/goal?

Comment: Problem: The animator does not work before uploading files.



Goal: The animator will run while loading the files, the Loading screen will appear. After the files are installed, -- " atorLoadingPanel.SetBool ("ActiveLoad", false);" -- will disappear from the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use actual Async in Unity unless you need to do some blocking IO, or heavy computations in another thread, unity only supports its engine calls to be executed on the main thread, so whatever you do in another thread need to be manually synchronized to the main thread.

The recommended way to account for waits is by using a Coroutine, which is fully thread safe in unity and lets you script a sequence of events very easily, for example

```
IEnumerator Example(string url)
{
  var www=new WWW(url);
  Debug.Log("Requesting "+url);
  yield return www;                 // wait for request to complete
  Debug.Log("Rquest completed");
  yield return new WaitForSeconds(1); // wait another second
  Debug.Log("Proceeding");
}
```

This will execute across multiple frames, while staying on the main thread

Answer (score 0):

Thank you zambari.

I need to look a little more at Coroutines :)

```
IEnumerator Example(string url, DateTime realToday, DateTime realFistDate)
{
    LoadingAnimator.SetBool("ActiveLoad", true);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    var www = new WWW(url);
    Debug.Log("Requesting " + url);
    while (realToday != realFistDate)
    {
        images.Add(realFistDate.ToString("dd.M.yyyy HH"), returnSprite(realFistDate, TypeString));
        imagesTime.Add(realFistDate.ToString("dd.M.yyyy HH"));
        realFistDate = realFistDate.AddHours(1);
    }
    yield return www;
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Rquest completed");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Proceeding");
    LoadingAnimator.SetBool("ActiveLoad", false);
    ShowData();
}
```

I solved my problem with this code block